# Understanding Qt platform variables

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I have a simple Qt `pro` file, with the purpose of being shared between different development platform, namely Windows 10 and a Linux distribution.

Hence I separated two sections in this file, where libraries, includes etc etc are system-dependent, and in this MWE are trivially two messages.

```
QT       += core gui
CONFIG += c++11

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = myappname
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    MultixWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    MultixWindow.h

FORMS    += MultixWindow.ui

win32
{
    message( "Running qmake for Windows" )
}

unix
{
    message( "Running qmake for Linux" )
}
```

What I don't understand is the fact that Qmake (I'm on Windows 10 x64) enters in both the sections! In other words, Qt Creator's *General Messages* log says

> Project MESSAGE: Running qmake for Windows
>
> Project MESSAGE: Running qmake for Linux

How should a cross-platform `pro` file be described ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Qmake Advanced usage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html) says,

> The opening brace must be written on the same line as the condition

So is just a matter of strict syntax.